# ItemsControl, ItemContainerStyle and ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf

Since I'm still struggling with understanding how ItemContainerStyle works, I tried to go to the root component that defines its behavior, that is ItemsControl.
The simplest application of style I can think of is trying to apply a couple of settings, let say the Background and the Foreground to the item.

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:VM></local:VM>
</Window.DataContext>

<DockPanel >
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">

        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style>
                <Setter Property="Control.Foreground" Value="red"/>
                <Setter Property="Control.Background" Value="yellow"/>
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                   
    </ItemsControl>
</Window>
```

The underlying class for the data is:

```
public class VM
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> Items { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    public VM()
    {
        Items.Add("first");
        Items.Add("second");
        Items.Add("third");
    }
}
```

The result:

[image: First test result]

Ok, background is not applied, but this is not what I wanted to check and BTW in WPF there seem to be more exceptions than rules. (And BTW2 i've already fighted with assigning the background of a ListBox selected item, that requires to retemplate the whole thing, maybe here it's similar? If you know the answer it's appreciated, but I leave it for now because it's taking me off track).

Let's also have a look at the Visual Tree:

[image: First test, Visual tree]

That is, for ItemsControl the items don't get a 'wrapper element'; if we do the same with a ListBox, for each item of the collection, it will be constructed a ListBoxItem.

Now let's try to template the item by adding this (just after `</ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>`) :

```
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemContainerTemplate>
        <Label MaxWidth="100" Content="{Binding}"/>
    </ItemContainerTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

This is the result (they are moved in the center because of the MaxWidth="100"; I wanted to see if there was something *behind*):

[image: First test, result]

The style is not applied anymore.  Let's have a look at the Viusal Tree:

[image: Second test, Visual tree]

This visual tree is not surprising, we just replaced default representation that before was a TextBlock. In its place now we find a Label with its own standard sub-tree.
What's surprising is that at least Foreground should apply to the label too, but unfortunately it doesn't.

#### What's going on then?

I've read a very similar question here:
[Can't use ItemTemplate and ItemContainerStyle together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28987424/cant-use-itemtemplate-and-itemcontainerstyle-together)
It differs from this in that it tries to assign the ContentTemplate. Since I'm still struggling with the basic behavior here (and I didn't understand the answer there except that there is some sort of copy-problem) I decided to put this more basic question.
However it seems there is a style-targeting problem here and *not* a copy problem; this is because if I keep the ItemTemplate, but replace the Label with a TextBlock (that leads to the very same VisualTree of the non-templated version) I get back my foreground red color!

```
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemContainerTemplate>
        <TextBlock MaxWidth="100" Text="{Binding}"/>
    </ItemContainerTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

#### Getting warmer?

So it seems that the framework checks if the component is TextBlock and if not doesn't apply the style.
But this is the default behavior when applying implicit styles: a stile with (TargetType == the type of the control being styled).
In this case it seems like the framework assumes that the TargetType is TextBlock, and never reconsiders this assumption even if ItemTemplate is set.

In order to better understand how the style-target works here I tryed to set the style's TargetType explicitly, who knwos, so let's try this:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="Label">
        <Setter Property="Label.Foreground" Value="red"/>
        <Setter Property="Label.Background" Value="yellow"/>
    </Style>
 </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
```

See the TargetType="Label"? Great. It gives the error:

Cant apply to ContentPresenter a style intended for Label.

(translated from italian, maybe not the exact wording in english. plz replace with the  exact one if you have it at hand).

That is, it expects this:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
        <Setter Property="Label.Foreground" Value="red"/>
        <Setter Property="Label.Background" Value="yellow"/>
    </Style>
</ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
```

It somewhat makes sense, because the root node of each item, according to the visual tree shown before is actually ContentPresenter.

At this point I'm quite confused: how is it supposed to work? The idea for the moment is that it doesn't.
The behavior for the subclasses like ListBox seems to be more sensible: it styles the container of the item; here a container for the item doesn't exist. That's just my guess because i couldn't find any documentation saying this.

Comment: "*for ItemsControl the items don't get a 'wrapper element'*" - wrong, the wrapper element is a ContentPresenter (similar to ListBoxItem for ListBox). "*The style is not applied anymore*" - in fact it is, however it has no effect. Set the Label's Foreground and Background instead. Also better use a simple [DataTemplate instead of a ItemContainerTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45033696/1136211). Futhermore, setting Label properties in a ItemContainerStyle is obviously pointless - regardless of the TargetType. Set them in the ItemTemplate, directly at the Label.

Comment: I found this series of articles very useful: [ItemsControl: A to Z](http://drwpf.com/blog/itemscontrol-a-to-z/). Describes the relationship between an items control and its container, how to correctly style things, how the different parts work together, and so on.

Comment: You figured out that the item in the ItemsControl is a container with an attachment.
But at the same time, you are wondering why, if you set a style to a container, its children will not inherit it.
In WPF, in principle, elements do not inherit the style from their parent.
What surprises you?
If you need to set values ​​for nested items, then you must set ItemTemplante.
This is exactly the same as styling and templating anywhere in XAML, on any element.

Comment: It surprises me that sometime it works :-). If I'm styling the container, and it doesn't pass the style down, why do the foreground become red in the first example?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking at your items and thinking about them when setting the ItemContainerStyle.

But of course this is their container you're setting a style on. The container of each item.  You don't really care about your container because it's not doing much.

Maybe a concrete example of a use case would be clearer than theory.

If you look at:

https://i.imgur.com/UZ6Nqrc.png

Those red and blue rectangles are units in this game.

Those are a variety of nato symbols indicating infantry, artillery cavalry etc.

An itemcontainerstyle is used to position them.

The whole panel on the left has an itemscontrol with a canvas as it's itemspanel ( instead of the default stackpanel ).

There is a viewmodel for each unit and a collection of these is bound to the itemssource of that itemscontrol.

A unit viewmodel has an X and Y property which is used to position the unit within that canvas.

The position of a unit is defined by a point which is the centre of it's view. Glossing over exactly why that is, I think this is interesting because the unit's viewmodel doesn't need to calculate the offset from centre to top left corner. This is done by a converter in the view and applied using a style:

```
<Style TargetType="ContentPresenter" x:Key="CenteredContentPresenter">
    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top">
        <Setter.Value>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{local:MultiAddConverter}">
                <Binding Path="Y" Mode="TwoWay"/>
                <Binding Path="ActualHeight"
                         Converter="{local:MultiplyConverter Multiplier=-.5}"
                         RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" 
                         Mode="TwoWay" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left">
        <Setter.Value>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{local:MultiAddConverter}">
                <Binding Path="X" Mode="TwoWay"/>
                <Binding Path="ActualWidth"  
                         Converter="{local:MultiplyConverter Multiplier=-.5}"
                         RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" 
                         Mode="TwoWay" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Elsewhere, in the map editor trees are positioned in a similar manner.

Answer (score 1):

The `ItemContainerStyle` is applied to the item containers that gets created by the virtual `GetContainerForItemOverride` method.

In the `ItemsControl` base class, this method returns a `ContentPresenter`:

```
protected virtual DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
{
    return new ContentPresenter();
}
```

In the derived `ListBox` class, it returns a `ListBoxItem`:

```
protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
{
    return new ListBoxItem();
}
```

The `TargetType` of the `ItemContainerStyle` must match the type of the `DependencyObject` returned from this method. Otherwise, you'll get an exception when the style is applied to the container(s) at runtime.